# Execute remote programs and completely detaching it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, ncurses

I need to execute a remote application (named ConnectionManager), which uses the ncurses library, on the remote server launching it from a local pc.

ConnectionManager is a program wich use ncurses and forks another process (itself) and waits for incoming tcp/ip connection.

On a:

```
Distributor ID: ScientificSL
Description:    Scientific Linux SL release 5.5 (Boron)
Release:        5.5
Codename:       Boron
(Like Centos5.5)
```

I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix
INFORMIXSERVER=server1_on
ONCONFIG=onconfig.eda
PATH=$PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/bin
export INFORMIXDIR INFORMIXSERVER ONCONFIG PATH
echo $INFORMIXSERVER
echo $ONCONFIG
echo "Launch ConnectionManager"
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xterm -e 'sudo -E /opt/informix/server /ConnectionManager'
```

and it all works.

The previous script doesn't work on

```
Distributor ID: Scientific
Description:    Scientific Linux release 6.4 (Carbon)
Release:        6.4
Codename:       Carbon
```

The ConnectionManager doesn't allow an IP connection.

I want to leave the ConnectionManager program running in a remote machine, also when I launch it from a local machine.

What's wrong?

I have tried `screen -d -m ./ConnectionManager`. The application works, but I don't see it on remote machine. I need to see the ConnectionManager within an xterm window.

Is it  possible that sudo is blocking ConnectionManager tcp/ip connections ?

Update: 
When I use this command: sudo './ConnectionManager'
I have immediately the following message:
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo './ConnectionManager'

I have check the code and the problem is the instruction `int setpgrp(void)` in ConnectionManager.

Why ?

Comment: don't understand much, but ... have you check firewall? if that is based on Centos, I believe it might have selinux. Is it enabled? did you chek /var/log/messages for errors?

Comment: There is no firewall, and selinux is disabled, if I run ./ConnectionManager working properly. It doesn't work only when I use the above script .

Comment: Consider using `screen`, `tmux` or some other terminal multiplexer to allow you to run a program independent of your own login session.

Comment: Hi Michael Kjörling, could you give me an example ? On the remote machine must be seen the ConnectionManager  within the an xterm window.

Comment: Do you need to be able to see the `xterm` that you're running the `sudo` command inside or is it enough to see the output from the `ConnectionManager` command?

Comment: I need to see the ConnectionManager window, it is an interactive program.

Comment: The problem is that the instruction sudo -E /opt/informix/server/ConnectionManager doesn't work

Comment: More likely `sudo` doesn't allow you to run `/opt/informix/server/ConnectionManager` with preserved environment (the `-E` option).

Comment: @peterph, But it's is allowed on SL 5.5. How can I allow the same on S.L. 6.4 ?

Comment: I have check the code and the problem is the instruction int setpgrp(void) in ConnectionManager.

Comment: The stop occurs when I use sudo, setpgrp() and ncurses instruction initscr()

Answer (score 0):

As @MichaelKjörling suggested in the comments you can run `ConnectionManager` or the script in a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux`.

With your example command you were almost all the way there:

```
$ screen -d -m ./ConnectionManager
```

Once this command runs you're detached from the terminal so you'd see no output after `ConnectionManager` starts up. You can reconnect to this particular screen session with this command:

```
$ screen -r
```

To disconnect from it you use the key combination <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. I always remember the mnemonic "attention" + "disconnect".

If you need to use the script, you can modify it slightly so that it too can also be run in a `screen` session.

```
#!/bin/bash
INFORMIXDIR=/opt/informix
INFORMIXSERVER=server1_on
ONCONFIG=onconfig.eda
PATH=$PATH:$INFORMIXDIR/bin
export INFORMIXDIR INFORMIXSERVER ONCONFIG PATH
echo $INFORMIXSERVER
echo $ONCONFIG
echo "Launch ConnectionManager"
sudo -E /opt/informix/server/ConnectionManager
```

You could then run this script the same way as `ConnectionManager` in a screen session:

```
$ screen -d -m yourscript.bash
```

And use the same connect, disconnect methods I mentioned above. With screen if you have more than one screen "session" you can use this command to list them out:

```
$ screen -ls
```

And then pick one from the list to connect to:

```
$ screen -r <name>
```

For example:

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    1506.bp (Detached)
    32090.dl    (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-root.

$ screen -r 32090.dl
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the problem is that the instruction `sudo -E /opt/informix/server/ConnectionManager` doesn't work